# Excel pivot table value as comma separated string

Tags: excel, pivot

I have following table in a excel sheet.

```
Risk  Type1  Type2
R1     H       H
R2     L       M
R3     M       L
R4     M       M
R5     M       H
R6     L       L
R7     H       M
R8     L       L
R9     H       H
R10    L       M
```

I want you use excel pivot table and get the following output.

```
                      Type2     
            H         M           L
      H R1, R9    R7    
Type1 M R5        R4          R3
      L           R2, R10     R6, R8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with a pivot table but you can download a function from [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx) and use an array formula like this:-

```
=stringconcat(",",IF(($B$2:$B$11=$E3)*($C$2:$C$11=F$2),$A$2:$A$11,""))
```

[image]